# Left join on the same table with a sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select *
from (select *
    from TableO to
    where to.week='22'
    and to.year='2018'
    ) as O 
   left join TableO lto on O.user_id=lto.user_id
where O.user_id IS NULL
```

I'm having problems with this query. Can anyone see what the mistake is?

I'm trying to left join on the same table, trying to find this part:

[image: Venn Diagram showing a left join]

Comment: May I ask what is the problem ? or you would rather not say ?

Comment: TableO is orders. In the sub query I want to find the orders for week 22, and by using left join I'm trying to find the user_id's that haven't had a new order since week 22.

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it.

Answer (score 0):

This will gives you user_id that ordered in 2018 but no order since week 22

```
select user_id 
from   TableO
where  year = 2018
group by user_id 
having max(week) <= 22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userid FROM TABLE1 
EXCEPT 
(SELECT userid FROM Table2 INTERSECT SELECT userid from table2)
```